# How many nested projections can be used with .Include()?

Tags: entity-framework, include

How many nested projections can be used with .Include() in the Entity Framework?

For example:

Class A has a List of Class B's, which has a list of Class C's, which has a list of Class D's, etc.

```
query.Include( a => a.BList.Select( b => b.Clist.Select( c => c.DList.Select(...) ) ) );
```

How far can these go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MSSQL - As Many as you want**

You can have as many nested projections as you wish when using Entity Framework with a MSSQL database. The query is formed by the `System.Data.SqlClient` when using MSSQL.

---

**MySQL - Only 2**

However, you can only use 2 projections before you begin to receive logical errors when using Entity Framework *with MySQL*. The MySql provider `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` has a ***[`bug`](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67183)*** where it will begin to produce failed joins after two projections. This bug was posted to Oracle, but never fixed.

Answer (score 1):

They can go as far as you want.  There is no programmatic limit, but I'm sure you would deplete some resource after a ridiculous amount of inclusions.